# Как создать MultiIndex DataFrame из трех DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, multi-index

Есть три DataFrame:

```py
df1
        Mkt-RF       SMB         HML             RMW             CMA
2150.T  0,010326672 -0,00683384 -0,015922939    -0,034126955    -0,027433946
2160.T  0,00694333  0,042082707 -0,018469847    -0,030172206    -0,039305427
2183.T  0,016815498 0,027305594 -0,001010234    0,013051465 -0,001653873
```

```py
df2
Date        2150.T      2160.T          2183.T 
2009-06-01  0,053003446 -0,054048795    0,372307744
2009-07-01  0,171141096 -0,142859592    0,311659124
```

```py
df3
Date        2150.T      2160.T      2183.T 
2009-06-01  0,195873784 0,001239748 0,221638138
2009-07-01  0,388427363 0,006662823 0,094775308
```

Надо создать MultiIndex DataFrame по этому примеру:

```py
result
                    df2             df3           df1 Mkt-RF     SMB          HML             RMW             CMA
2009-06-01  2150.T  0,053003446     0,195873784     0,010326672 -0,00683384 -0,015922939    -0,034126955    -0,027433946
            2160.T  -0,054048795    0,001239748     0,00694333  0,042082707 -0,018469847    -0,030172206    -0,039305427
            2183.T  0,372307744     0,221638138     0,016815498 0,027305594 -0,001010234    0,013051465 -0,001653873

2009-07-01  2150.T  0,171141096     0,388427363     0,010326672 -0,00683384 -0,015922939    -0,034126955    -0,027433946
            2160.T  -0,142859592    0,006662823     0,00694333  0,042082707 -0,018469847    -0,030172206    -0,039305427
            2183.T  0,311659124     0,094775308     0,016815498 0,027305594 -0,001010234    0,013051465 -0,001653873
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = (df2
       .set_index("Date")
       .stack()
       .to_frame(name="df2")
       .join(df3
             .set_index("Date")
             .stack()
             .to_frame(name="df3"))
       .rename_axis(["Date", "yr"]))

res = res.join(df1.rename_axis("yr"))
```

---

результат:

```
In [53]: res
Out[53]:
                            df2          df3       Mkt-RF          SMB           HML           RMW           CMA
Date       yr
2009-06-01 2150.T   0,053003446  0,195873784  0,010326672  -0,00683384  -0,015922939  -0,034126955  -0,027433946
           2160.T  -0,054048795  0,001239748   0,00694333  0,042082707  -0,018469847  -0,030172206  -0,039305427
           2183.T   0,372307744  0,221638138  0,016815498  0,027305594  -0,001010234   0,013051465  -0,001653873
2009-07-01 2150.T   0,171141096  0,388427363  0,010326672  -0,00683384  -0,015922939  -0,034126955  -0,027433946
           2160.T  -0,142859592  0,006662823   0,00694333  0,042082707  -0,018469847  -0,030172206  -0,039305427
           2183.T   0,311659124  0,094775308  0,016815498  0,027305594  -0,001010234   0,013051465  -0,001653873
```

Comment: Разобрался в **df1** убрал **Unnamed: 0** в индексе `df1 = file.pd_read_csv('df1.csv', index_col=0)`. Огромное спасибо.